# `min_score` doesn't work for `rescore` in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, min

I hope to remove all documents having a score less than `1` but the following query doesn't work:

```
curl "http://localhost:9200/megacorp/_search" -d '{
  "min_score": 1,
  "query": {
    "matchAll": {}
  },
  "rescore": {
    "query": {
      "score_mode": "min",
      "rescore_query": {
        "match": {"first_name": "Jane"}
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

It looks `min_score` doesn't work for `rescore`.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: @user It's `score_mode`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed up the concept of `min_score` and `rescore`. Both are used for different purpose.

The `min_score` is applied to **initial** query. In your case it is `match_all` query so every single document is returned with the score of 1 and **this score** is checked against `min_score` **regardless** of what `rescore` does.

The `rescore` is used to affect the `scoring` of returned documents(Your initial query). It doesn't affect the `count` of results, only the `order` of results. so even if `"match": {"first_name": "Jane"}` score less than 1, it will be shown. similarly if you use `score_mode: total` and total score is greater than 1,but if original query's score is less than 1,it wont be shown in results.

You can use [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to learn about how score is computed. Finally if you want to play with `scoring`, you could look into [script_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) or [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

I hope this clears the doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You mean `rescore` is not affected by `min_score` by design, right? If so, is there a way to remove unwanted results based on rescored scores after `rescore`?

Comment: glad I could help. Yes you could remove unwanted results but You would have to iterate through every single returned document and check its `_score` because that would be the score computed after rescore query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't want to get unwanted documents from Elasticsearch due to unnecessary network and computation costs. Is it possible to filter them out in Elasticsearch, not in applications?

Comment: I am not aware of anything like that, only thing I can suggest is putting you rescore query inside main query but that is not something you want I guess.